# How can I change the page on clicking the dots of UIPageControl

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

Here I have a `pagecontrol` which works good but on clicking on dot it doesn't change the page so please help in the function of `changepage`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    scrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 420)];
    scrollView.delegate = self;
    [self.scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [scrollView setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];
    scrollView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
    scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    [scrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
    scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
    pageControl=[[UIPageControl alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 420, 320, 40)];
    [pageControl addTarget:self action:@selector(changepage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:pageControl];
    
    UIView *blueView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    blueView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 640, 480);
    blueView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [scrollView addSubview:blueView];
    self.pageControl.numberOfPages = 2;
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(640, 0)];
}

-(void)changepage:(id)sender
{
    int page = pageControl.currentPage;
    if (page < 0)
        return;
    if (page >= 2)
        return;
    CGRect frame = scrollView.frame;
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
    
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)_scrollView
{
    if (pageControlIsChangingPage)
        return;
    CGFloat pageWidth = _scrollView.frame.size.width;
    int page = floor((_scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
    pageControl.currentPage = page;
}
```

Comment: what is the question ? I didn't understand what is the issue ?

Comment: @pranjal sir i want to move the page on clicking the dots of pagecontrol

Comment: go through the link http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/pagecontrol-example-in-iphone/

Comment: i have done this programatically. i haven't understood the tutorials because they use xibs.i have gone through many

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can create one event change page:

```
- (IBAction)changePage:(id)sender {
    UIPageControl *pager=sender;
    int page = pager.currentPage;
    CGRect frame = imageGrid_scrollView.frame;
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    [imageGrid_scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
}
```

Bind it to Pagecontrol's value changed event.

Answer (score 14):

This is very useful for pagecontrol dots click action change page index for ***swift 3*** and ***swift 4*** .

```
@IBAction func pageControlSelectionAction(_ sender: UIPageControl) {
    let page: Int? = sender.currentPage
    var frame: CGRect = self.yourcollectionview.frame
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * CGFloat(page ?? 0)
    frame.origin.y = 0
    self.yourcollectionview.scrollRectToVisible(frame, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: perfect. Works for me.

Comment: valueChanged event always moves one page forward/backward. How to detect exact dot tapped?

Answer (score 5):

Just to complete Banker Mittal's answer, the easiest way to do it in swift is to scroll the wanted rect to visible. You don't have to take care of "left" and "right" scrolling because iOS itself realizes which dot you tapped so you can just scroll to the correct frame:

```
private func moveScrollViewToCurrentPage() {

 //You can use your UICollectionView variable too instead of my scrollview variable
            self.scrollView
                .scrollRectToVisible(CGRect(
                    x: Int(self.scrollView.frame.size.width) * self.pager.currentPage,
                    y: 0,
                     width:Int(self.scrollView.frame.size.width),
                    height: Int(self.scrollView.frame.size.height)),
                                     animated: true)

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a ***Swift 2*** Solution for `UICollectionView`.
Clicking the `UIPageControl's dots` moves your current view to the left or to the right.

```
// Define bounds
private var currentIndex:Int = 0
private let maxLimit = 25
private let minLimit = 0

// Define @IBAction from UIPageControl
@IBAction func moveViewLeftRight(sender: UIPageControl) {
    // Move to Right
    if currentIndex < maxLimit && sender.currentPage > currentIndex {
        currentIndex++
        self.collectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forItem: currentIndex, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: .Right, animated: true)
    // Move to Left
    } else if currentIndex > minLimit {
        currentIndex--
        self.collectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forItem: currentIndex, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: .Left, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Having a scrollRectToVisible is also more easy. But in case you wanted to scroll to an item in your CollectionView you can just pass sender.currentPage. The system applies the tapped dot as current page.