# How to Capture click event on Page Control swift

Tags: ios, swift

I follow a tutorial on how to create  `UIPageControl` and when I click on the page indicator it do not change the page

```
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    guard let viewControllerIndex = orderedViewControllers.index(of: viewController) else {
        return nil
    }
    let previousIndex = viewControllerIndex - 1
    // User is on the first view controller and swiped left to loop to
    // the last view controller.
    guard previousIndex >= 0 else {
        return orderedViewControllers.last
        // Uncommment the line below, remove the line above if you don't want the page control to loop.
        // return nil
    }

    guard orderedViewControllers.count > previousIndex else {
        return nil
    }

    return orderedViewControllers[previousIndex]
}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    guard let viewControllerIndex = orderedViewControllers.index(of: viewController) else {
        return nil
    }

    let nextIndex = viewControllerIndex + 1
    let orderedViewControllersCount = orderedViewControllers.count
    // User is on the last view controller and swiped right to loop to
    // the first view controller.
    guard orderedViewControllersCount != nextIndex else {
        return orderedViewControllers.first
        // Uncommment the line below, remove the line above if you don't want the page control to loop.
        // return nil
    }

    guard orderedViewControllersCount > nextIndex else {
        return nil
    }

    return orderedViewControllers[nextIndex]
}

func configurePageControl() {
    // The total number of pages that are available is based on how many available colors we have.
    pageControl = UIPageControl(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY - 40,width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width,height: 40))
    self.pageControl.numberOfPages = orderedViewControllers.count
    self.pageControl.currentPage = 0
    self.pageControl.tintColor = UIColor.gray
    self.pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.gray
    self.pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.white
    self.view.addSubview(pageControl)
}
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
    let pageContentViewController = pageViewController.viewControllers![0]
    self.pageControl.currentPage = orderedViewControllers.index(of: pageContentViewController)!

}
```

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13854222/how-can-i-change-the-page-on-clicking-the-dots-of-uipagecontrol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `configurePageControl()` add  `pageControl.addTarget`

```
func configurePageControl() {
        // The total number of pages that are available is based on how many available colors we have.
         pageControl = UIPageControl(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY - 40,width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width,height: 40))

        //add target for dots
        pageControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.pageControlSelectionAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.pageControl.numberOfPages = orderedViewControllers.count
        self.pageControl.currentPage = 0
        self.pageControl.tintColor = UIColor.gray
        self.pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.gray
        self.pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.white
        self.view.addSubview(pageControl)
    }
```

Then add the method to change page when a dot is selected.

```
 @objc func pageControlSelectionAction(_ sender: UIPageControl) {
        //move page to wanted page
        let page: Int? = sender.currentPage
        self.pageViewController?.setViewControllers([[orderedViewControllers[page!]]], direction: .forword, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: Hi there, I tried this solution but I am getting this error 'Reference to member 'setViewControllers' cannot be resolved without a contextual type'.

Answer (score 3):

In my case(Xcode 13), I received previous currentPage.
So use dispatchQueue asyncAfter

```
@objc func pageControlSelectionAction(_ sender: UIPageControl) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1, execute: { 
       let page: Int? = sender.currentPage
       //scroll
    }
}
```

Also I just tested 'DispatchQueue.main.async' was fine.